# Deploying a modified vendor asset to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have Jquery-datatables-rails gem installed. When you install the gem via bundle a folder is created under `.rvm/gems/RUBY@GEMSET/gems/jquery-datatables-rails`

Inside of this folder you can browse to the vendor/assets folder and modify the CSS, etc.

The only problem is that upon deployment a remote version of the gem is installed on the remote production instance, which does not reflect the local changes.

Is there any way to ensure the local modifications are pushed to Heroku?

Thanks

Comment: Right so someone helped me with this. What I need to do is fork the gem and host it on my github and link my gemfile to the forked gem. Duh ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can fork the gem and point to it on github as you mentioned, or you can make the changes to your local assets directory which will speed up the time it takes to compile your app on Heroku.

Comment: Ok, regarding the second option you mention, how would I do that? As I mentioned when I modded the directory the local asset wasn't pushed to heroku.

Comment: Put it in your app directly and not in  the gem vendor directory so under app/assets/whatever(.js|.css) and load it in under application.css or application.js if it's css it shouldn't really matter what order its loaded in.

Comment: Would there be a conflict with the unmodified gem vendor stylesheet loaded remotely on heroku? How do I know that my stylesheet would supersede the vender stylesheet remotely?

Comment: If it works locally, it should work on Heroku. Try uninstalling your gem adding those css changes to your local project and then inspecting your changes with chrome's web inspector, if the styles don't match up try more specific selectors. If it takes any amount of time it may be easier for you to just use the GIT solution you mentioned.